# How to modify inno setup generated default uninstaller code so that it runs some extra user defined scripts before cleaning up registry enties

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, uninstallation

I have written an installer which creating some files outside(according to user's choices) program file folder. So while running the uninstall task it is only cleaning up the registry entry and program file entries but not the files created outside.
Now I can not use [UninstallDelete] section to remove those files since simple removal will not work for them. I need to run some script to do that and also before removing registry entry not after.

My question is :

Is there a way so that I can change the default uninstaller for running some extra user-defined script like the installer does?

Comment: Though it's not clear to me what prevent the uninstaller from cleaning the files on its own. Nor why `UninstallDelete` won't work.

Comment: in [uninstallrun] section I can add some script which will run before uninstall script run. But the outcome of that script should decide to run or not to run unins000.exe. Is that possible ?

Comment: Sure, that can be done. But that's a very different question than the one you have asked. So please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I think I got the answer from the post you have pointed out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then please consider upvoting the post that helped you.